# Why has CFM International changed the profile of the fan struts used at their CFM 56 turbofan?

Tags: jet-engine

The shape of the horizontal struts has changed. See images with arrows indicating the struts cited:

[image]

Image of a early version of a CFM56 turbofan showing the fan struts

[image]

Image of a CFM56 7B26 showing the fan struts

Comment: Maybe it hasn't changed, only that the aft airfoil-ish part of the strut was omitted from the first display model (which also lacks a bunch of plumbing and wiring).